# How to reference a hiera variable from elsewhere the hierarchy?

Tags: puppet, hiera

So suppose in a very specific hiera YAML file I define a variable, such as "env_name".

> env_name: "dev-unstable"

Now in a more general hiera file I'd like to interpolate that variable into a string.

> server_name: "service-%{env_name}.%{::domain}"

My testing seems to imply that hiera variables from elsewhere in the hierarchy aren't made available for interpolation in general cases. Is that true, unfortunately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Hiera lookup functions within Hiera. Documentation here: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/variables.html#using-lookup-functions

In your case you would use:

```
server_name: "service-%{hiera('env_name')}.%{::domain}"
```

This is a priority lookup and will get the value for the key `env_name` from the highest (most specific) hierarchy level in which it finds the key.

This requires Hiera 1.3 or higher.

Answer (score 6):

For Hiera 5, used in Puppet 5+, use the following syntax:

```yaml
server_name: "service-%{lookup('env_name')}.%{::domain}"
```

...where `%{lookup('env_name')}` is the part that gets the data from the other hiera key, `env_name`.

([Source](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/8/hiera_automatic.html#hiera_dotted_notation))

Comment: Note: save yourself an hour and notice that there is a Puppet `lookup`  function and a Hiera `lookup` function with different signatures. The documentation is not clear about this (just includes a subnote) and as a reader, it is very difficult to search for one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer from Greg Dubicki.

To quote
"The hiera, hiera_array, hiera_hash, and hiera_include functions are all deprecated. The lookup function is a complete replacement for all of these."

For details see:

https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/hiera_migrate.html#updated_classic_hiera_function_calls